# Background property in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have seen many sites using background image for their page but then i see the following code

```
background: url(...) no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
```

I couldn't understand the different  property used after the url. I need to understand those properties.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Comment: you can try and visit this page : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Comment: These properties (after URL) can be defined under "background" as these are part of background only and describe how the image will appear. have a look here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Comment: You should really spend 5 minutes doing some research before asking a question. This is easily found online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will explain property after image url

1- background repeat : you can disable repeat it with "no-repeat" option so it show once but if its small you have to put background color to fill the rest white spaces .. also you can repeat it horizontal only with "repeat-x" and vertical with "repeat-y"

2-scroll/fixed : it means your background image is scrolling with content till its end .. or you can use option "fixed" to sticky background and only scroll content/elements !

3-background-position : this option to position background in page .. first attribute for horizontal position you can set option "right" or "center" or "left" and next attribute is vertical position and you can use "top" or "center" or "bottom"

4- background color -> use transparent or specify color to fill the page behind background image so if the image is small and you set it to no-repeat the color will fill the rest spaces on web page !!

hope this make you understand :) and sorry for my english